# How do I say Newsflash in german?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I want to make a sarcastic comment under a youtube video of an interview with Christiano Ronaldo. I want something along the lines of 'Newsflash: Christiano Ronaldo says his life is pretty good'.

Comment: You can use mramosch's answer, but you could just say Newsflash, everyone will understand it.

Comment: @Paul: At least everyone under a certain age (or 'Falco - Jeanny' fans)... - Older people or people who's english is not that well won't understand...

Answer (score 4):

*Eilmeldung* is another word that's frequently used in German for this.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can use "Newsflash" without translating it - as indicated by Paul in a comment), in particular on a site like Youtube.

If you are looking for more "German" versions - which do stray a bit from your original sentence, but convey the meaning:

```
Ganz was Neues: Cristiano Ronaldo ist tatsächlich mit seinem Leben zufrieden.

Überraschung: Cristiano Ronaldo ist tatsächlich mit seinem Leben zufrieden.

Echt? Cristiano Ronaldo ist tatsächlich mit seinem Leben zufrieden?
```

Answer (score 1):

***Aktuelle Kurzmeldung:*** etc.

would be a good fit...